# Заполнить массив отмеченными элементами CheckedListBox

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, visual-c++

Существует `CheckedListBox` под именем `Files` и массив `FilePathes`. Нужно в режиме реального времени иметь в массиве все те элементы, которые отмечены в `CheckedListBox'е`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте свойства `CheckedIndices` и/или `CheckedItems`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатывать событие ItemCheck:

```
Void Files_ItemCheck(Object^ sender, ItemCheckEventArgs^ e) {
    if (e->NewValue == CheckState::Checked) {
        // добавляем Files->Items[e->Index] в массив
    } else {
        // ищем в массиве Files->Items[e->Index] и удаляем
    }
}
```